# CodeIgniter: 404 Page not found after push for server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I did some apps on my local machine, runs ok, but after send that to the server I am getting 404 error page, I tried all methods but none works, can you help me with that?

a2enmod rewrite is on.

I found in google I need use in the server the same version of my php I have in my localmachine or my app will not run, that is true?

my local:
application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8888/app/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

my server:
application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/app';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

I tried too:
application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I got stuck on that, can you help me with that?

Comment: what are you working on really?

Comment: If your using codeigniter 3.0 make sure all your controllers and models start with a capital letter Welcome.php http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-62172.html more htaccess https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Comment: OMG :), your right dude, i just renamed my controller = from user.php to User.php , and works perfect on website, upvoted :) thank you, just a question do u know why that happen? i am just curious now.

Comment: wolfgang1983 you can leave a answer i will upvote you, cheers dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was: in controllers was like that: user.php so i renamed for User.php, i not understand well that, but fixed online my code.

using user.php run in my local but not in live, if somebody know why, please leave a comment too.

thanks all for the help.

cheers.

Comment: That's a CodeIgniter 3 convention for controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Do This Configurations

In your `config.php`

1. `$config['base_url']    = '';`
2. `$config['index_page'] = '';`
3. `$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

in `config/routes.php` file

```
$route['default_controller'] = '';//default controller name
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

then in `.htaccess`(**this should be place out side of application folder**)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hello Abdulla, i did but i am still getting the error :(

Comment: what is your site URL??

Comment: there is no controller call in `holiday-helper`

Comment: can you show me your controller code. Modify your answer and post it there

Comment: just load model `$this->load->model('User_model');`

Comment: i did the changes u said and still the same :(

Comment: @Abdulla - What is `config/routs.php`?

Comment: @Raduken If this help please **[Mark it as ACCEPT**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Hence [**VOTE UP** will lead my TAG count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in your `.htaccess` file, you are not providing access for your CodeIgniter Directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i am very confused now, i have 2 .htaccess right now, 1 inside application and another outside application, its that ok?, i tried your code too, but still not working :(

Comment: keep only 1, that is inside your project. and try my code. in 3rd line write your actual project directory name in place of "app".

Comment: sorry, just keep 1 which is inside.