# CodeIgniter fresh install not working with xampp fresh install

Tags: php, codeigniter

I downloaded CodeIgniter 3.x and a new xampp with a php 5.6.8 on it.
After deploying the CI on the htdocs folder and accessing it through the browser, I'm getting 404 Page Not Found.

I'm very sure that the error page is from CI because I am familiar with CI's 404 error page (design and layout) and I know it's not from the browser or server.

Comment: Have you experienced this before? Have you tried reinstalling them? Can you share a bit more of your installation environment? Have you followed the steps in the user guide? Sharing more information should be useful.

Comment: Have you added any controllers other than the welcome page?

Comment: u are getting 404 error that means ur URL is wrong or/and you have not placed CI installation files in a proper location

Comment: How to produce the error?I could not produce the error.

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you changed from the default installation? Have you added any pages yet? What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: Thanks guys, but I solved it somehow. The problem is not with the codeigniter, but on the path of my directory. For those asking if I added controller or edited config files, no I didn't, because I stated in the title that it is "Fresh Installed". I wonder why some people downvoted my question

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason behind error `404 Page Not Found` is that Controller or Controller's Method is not found by CI Framework.

For that, you check out CI Naming Convention with your Controller Name and Its File Name.

Make sure all your files must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner.

Or-else grab the fresh installation from

http://www.codeigniter.com/download

Comment: Need some more information regarding your problem.! you can share some code from your project like route.php(config), welcome.php(controller) and your directory structure or screen shots. Anything would be helpful.

Comment: It's actually a "Fresh Install", so that automatically means I did not touch a single character on the files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check config/config.php, .htaccess, controller name(Should follow the name convention of Controller according CI3),
And also try these solutions

[CodeIgniter: 404 Page not found after push for server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861466/codeigniter-404-page-not-found-after-push-for-server/30863813#30863813)